# Share Photo with link and custom Graph story Facebook 4.0

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am using the following code to share a custom graph story using openGraph

```
SharePhotophoto=newSharePhoto.Builder() .setBitmap(icon)
 .setUserGenerated(true) .build();


                                    // Create an object
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
.putString("og:type", "exadigitalann:milestone")
.putString("og:title", "Digital Anniversaries")
.putString("og:description", genGree.greeting(_id, dateinDB, preeting, radio,
B, name, notification_data, image, notification_data_greet, dost,
notification))                                       
.putPhoto("og:image", photo)
.build();


                                    // Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
.setActionType("exadigitalann:celebrating")
.putObject("milestone", object)
.build();

                                    // Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
.setPreviewPropertyName("milestone")
.setAction(action)                                             
.build();
ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

Everything was working fine:

[image]

All the elements are present - The image, If I click on the story it takes me to the website configured - I have the action and object types displaying, and the details below that - perfect.

Yesterday I tried this again and this is what I get when I post: 
[image]

As you can see its just an image now, if I click on it it just displays the image full screen.

I re read the facebook developer docs and it states that:

> To attach pictures of a book to the books.reads action, an app should
>   load images as a Bitmap and pass those to the Share dialog when it's
>   opened. Example:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
.setBitmap(bitmap)
.setUserGenerated(true)
.build();

SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
.addPhoto(photo)
.build();
```

However there is no word on where I need to add the `content` of the type `SharePhotoContent` thus generated? Where does it fit?

I realize that if I switch the flag `User Generated` to false everything works as intended, I am just looking to do things properly here.

A working code example would be great.

Comment: You add the `content` to either the ShareDialog object, or the ShareApi object.

Comment: Hello Ming Li, thanks for the help. Here I have one more question, How do I detect the facebook app on the device, if I want to fall back to a share dialog if the ap is not present. As it stands I can only share the link part with a web dialog, so how do I detect?

Comment: The ShareDialog will automatically fall back. You can also check using the canShow() methods on the ShareDialog. So you can add a bitmap to the PhotoContent, add it to the ShareDialog, check the canShow() method, and if it returns false, try a link instead.

Comment: Thanks MingLi I will give it a try and let you know :)